# How do you change an element's attribute from document.getElementByClass within a for loop?

Tags: javascript

How do you populate multiple patterns on load? I can't get this to work:

```
function IPPattern() {
    for(i = 0; i < document.getElementByClass("IPForm").length; i++){
        document.getElementByClass("IPForm")[i].pattern = "somregex";
    };
}

<body onload="IPPattern();">

<input placeholder="Enter IP address..." type="text" class="IPForm" required>
```

Comment: is pattern a attribute ?

Comment: Use [`data-` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) for custom attributes.

Comment: That looks like it could be helpful, but it doesn't allow for a lot of backwards compatibility. I'd like to support a bit more than HTML5+.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all you can’t set your own attributes like this. The correct code is:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("IPForm")[i].setAttribute("pattern", "somregex");
```

My second remark is that the function is `getElementsByClassName()` not `getElementByClassName()`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I didn't reference getElement.  
This method didn't work.  
I tried the following:  
  
'document.getElementByClass("IPForm")[i].setAttribute("pattern","someregex");};}'  
  
and based on what @nick-graeff said I tried  
  
'document.getElementByClassName("IPForm")[i].setAttribute("pattern","someregex");};}'

Comment: I obviously meant `getElementByClassName()`. It’s ElementS not Element.

Answer (score 0):

For one, it's `getElementsByClassName`, not `getElementByClass`.

Besides that, you shouldn't be selecting elements by their classname. Use id instead. Classes are normally reserved for CSS.

```
var ipform = document.getElementsByClassName("ipform")
for (i = 0; i < ipform.length; i++) {
    ipform[i].setAttribute("pattern", "someregex");
}
```

Comment: The challenge is that I already use the ID to call each form for the function that will be processed on submit. Each form is different, therefore, each ID is different. 

id="IPForm1"
id="IPForm2"

and so on. That's why I chose to use class.

Comment: Are you trying to check the user didn't enter something invalid or malicious? If so you should just have the whole thing output a json object and then check it against some regex.

Comment: Yes. I'm not familiar with what you mean by JSON object. The code I'm trying to improve is at security.schvenn.ca and I'm trying to limit the code to javascript, because it's the only thing with which I have any familiarity.

Comment: You can **never** use JavaScript for security, cause the user can disable it.

Comment: True but in this case it isn't communicating with anything back end so it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Correct. There is no back end. It's for input validation not security. Sorry, I should have specified that more clearly.

Comment: What specifically didn't work? That code runs assuming all your inputs have the class name `ipform`.

Comment: When I add that script to the page, the text field has no validation pattern. It accepts any input.